# Updating bubble chart with forceSimulation without changing the positions of old bubbles

Tags: d3.js

I want to implement a bubble chart that changes dynamically over time like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqgYRfmn06M) using D3.js v5.

If you run the following code and move the slide bar, you will find the positions of the bubbles that appeared in the previous step are changing, which makes the transition between steps "jumpy".

How can I keep the positions of the bubbles that appeared in the previous step as much as possible and update only their bubble sizes?

In other words, given a sequence of sets of key/value pairs, how can I update these pairs without letting them collide each other using `forceSimulation`, while keeping the x, y positions of the keys that have already appeared in the previous time step?

```js
var data = [
 [{text:"a", size: 500},{text:"b", size: 300},{text:"c", size: 150},{text:"d", size: 100},{text:"e", size: 200}],
  [{text:"a", size: 400},{text:"b", size: 200},{text:"c", size: 100},{text:"x", size: 300},{text:"y", size: 300}],
  [{text:"a", size: 200},{text:"b", size: 100},{text:"x", size: 300},{text:"y", size: 350},{text:"z", size: 200}],
  [{text:"a", size: 500},{text:"b", size: 300},{text:"c", size: 150},{text:"d", size: 100},{text:"e", size: 200}],
  [{text:"a", size: 400},{text:"b", size: 200},{text:"c", size: 100},{text:"x", size: 300},{text:"y", size: 300}]
  ]
  
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .style("position", "absolute")
  .style("z-index", "10")
  .style("visibility", "hidden")
  .style("color", "white")
  .style("padding", "8px")
  .style("background-color", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)")
  .style("border-radius", "6px")
  .style("font", "14px sans-serif")
  .text("tooltip");

var width = 300,
  height = 300,
  color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemePastel1)

var svg = d3.select("#chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("width", width)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")

var circles = svg.selectAll(".node");
var texts = svg.selectAll(".text");

var radiusScale = d3.scaleSqrt().domain([100, 400]).range([10, 40])


var slider = d3.select("#slider")
  .append("input")
  .attr("class", "slider")
  .attr("type", "range")
  .attr("min", 0)
  .attr("max", data.length - 1)
  .attr("value", 0)
  .attr("style", "width:300px")
  .on("change", function(d) {
    update(data[this.value]);
  })

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("x", d3.forceX())
  .force("y", d3.forceY())
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
    return radiusScale(d.size) + 1;
  }))
  .on('tick', ticked)

// Initial update
update(data[0])

function update(data) {
  var t = d3.transition()
    .duration(750);

  //For circles
  //JOIN
  circles = circles.data(data, function(d) {
    return d.text
  })

  //EXIT
  circles.exit().remove()

  //ENTER
  circles = circles
    .enter().append("circle")
    .merge(circles)

  circles
    .transition(t)
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return radiusScale(d.size)
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return color((d.text[0].charCodeAt()))
    })

  circles
   .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        tooltip.html("Word: " + d.text + "<br>Frequency: " + d.size)
        tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
      })
    .on("mousemove", function() {
      return tooltip
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 10) + "px")
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px")
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
    })
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended))

  //For texts
  //JOIN
  texts = texts.data(data, function(d) {
    return d.text
  })

  //EXIT
  texts.exit().remove()

  //ENTER
  texts = texts
    .enter().append("text")
    .merge(texts)

  texts
    .transition(t)
    .attr("class", "text")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.text
    })

  simulation.nodes(data)
  simulation.alpha(1).restart();
}

function ticked() {
  circles
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y
    })

  texts
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.x
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return d.y
    })

}

// make circles dragable
function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
  tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}
```

```css
.node:hover {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  opacity: .7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v0.3.min.js"></script>

<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="chart"></div>
```